# Do I need to remove testDevice code for AdView in android before publishing?

Tags: android, admob

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewGame);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("27CBA8D2XXXXXXXXXD7996125")
    .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Do I need to remove any line from the above code before generating the signed apk for publishing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's a unique id for your device, So if you tried to install this app from the PlayStore on this device you will see the test ads not the real one.

Also i published my app with the same code and no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are actually requesting ads using a live/prod ad unit ID! However, I'd remove the test device ID for two reasons.

- First of all, it's not really doing anything there.  It's a way for the SDK to tell if a device is yours, and deliver test ads on it.  However, now that your app is on the Play Store, you don't need that offer anymore.
- Second, it's a unique device ID so you wouldn't want it flying about out of your hands.  Security reasons.

Comment: There *is* a purpose to leaving the test device code in your published app, which is that it allows you to test the published version on your test device without using real ads. That means you can test with the same builds you submit to the Play/App store, and even test after publication. The device IDs used have been put through a one-way hash (like passwords are), so security should not be an issue.